From chosen people to drifters and all that between
If I may make the assumption that our reality IS NOT a random chaos, then some interesting ideas have room for discussion.
Assuming this God's World or a Computer Simulator has some goals and milestones for human society. Then we should expect some script writing, creative directing, and local interference (from beyond) influencing our reality.
And, as in respectable theater, you would have people chosen for leading roles (movers and shakers) and people on the other side of the spectrum, all the way to some homeless man, all forgotten and unimportant.
Did you see philosophical works developed in the same line of thinking?

BTW while the question is clear enough for the most part, the part about "some homeless man, all forgotten and unimportant" in the context of theatre is not

@Rushi - I hoped that other people do realize that there is no equality when it comes to the "influence from above". Some people play an active role and receive more influence. But others are mostly background, or even worse, lost their role, and drifting along.

Oho the Democracy Dogma  Yeah!
Because democracy is good axiomatically, and God does not look very (USA standard) democratic so God is not good or God is not God. It's good to remember: For Aristotle, democracy is failure-modr government. And while in the modern fashion the opposite of democracy is tyranny, in the original, the opposite is hierarchy. And hierarchy by definition is religion. (See the etymology) So pragmatically democracy is the synonym of atheism. It is not happenstance that the US democratic party is the anti religion party

So the more pragmatic answer to how to progress from forgotten in the wings to star performer is like: Christian? Pray! Buddhist? Meditate! Sikh? Serve! Muslim? Fast! Hindu? All of the above . But beware what you wish for! Star pperformers can end up on the cross!

@Rushi - You are looking from a personal perspective. This is what most people do. What is good for me? What can I do to be more important? How can I earn my happiness? But if you are a smart actor, you will think rather about what the main producer needs or wants. Or, if you are a genius actor, you will realize that this play has a bad end, and you would rather not have any role at all.

I used to be passionate about the US (Trump) election. But, after Trump's ear, I realized that the Matrix is cooking something, and our role is just to sit and watch.

I don't disagree at all. All the "star performers" have 2 faces. One we see, the other leaks out kinda sorta in their "private conversations with God/Matrix" That then returns to your question: How do I get God's email address? See comment above. And remember the well known 1 to 100 assurance.

In this theater (our reality), you don't ask for a role. But you listen for clues and feel when you've been auditioned for a potential role.

All spiritual traditions directly or indirectly talk of connection.  In the theistic traditions it is usually in the form of connection to God ie. prayer.
The more secular traditions like Vipassana talk of it more directly and self reflexively — to connect with one's own body/sensations/breathing etc.
From any of these, it is a short step to the recognition that mediation/prayer/spiritual practices etc change the world.

Carl Jung: Who looks outward, dreams; who looks inward, awakes.

Thomas Merton: The contemplative life…has an impact on the whole world…for it brings the knowledge of love and peace into the midst of the struggle and hatred and fear.

Ralph Waldo Emerson: What lies behind us and what lies before us are tiny matters compared to what lies within us.

Ramana Maharshi: Your own Self-realization is the greatest service you can render the world.


While these may seem far fetched to those brought up on materialism, Lao Tzu maps out the path nicely:

Cultivate virtue in yourself, and it will be true.
Cultivate it in the family, and it will overflow.
Cultivate it in the village, and it will grow.
Cultivate it in the nation, and it will be abundant.
Cultivate it in the universe, and it will be everywhere.

And then in reverse:

Therefore:
See others as yourself.
See families as your family.
See towns as your town.
See countries as your country.
See worlds as your world.
Tao te Ching 54


This Rumi quote suggested by CriglCragl also points to “connection”  on a cosmic scale.

I died as mineral and became a plant, I died as plant and rose to animal, I died as animal and I was human.
Why should I fear?  When was I less by dying?
Yet once more I shall die human, To soar with angels blessed above. And when I sacrifice my angel soul I shall become what no mind ever conceived.


@KristianBerry I'm always grateful for those who explain their votes — so thanks! But I must confess to being none the wiser for your laconic comment. Could you laymanize it for me pls?? Maybe like Youre BSing Or maybe OP is deluded and you are exploiting that I really cant make out. I can only (very vaguely) make out that you seem to be hitting on the OP more than on me? If so maybe you want to raise it on meta? Laconic but indecipherable comments dont really help any you know! I only hope its not unrelated concerns creeping in/leaking out

BTW 'mystical apophenia' (1st time I am encountering the word!) seems either a tautology or an oxymoron. Mystics almost by definition see things that ordinary ppl dont. As you may know Blake is a classic favorite of mine. You can say he's talking nonsense — in which case he's not a mystic, just deluded. Or he is a mystic talking profound truth in which case its not apophenia but clear vision that others dont happen to have. We cant have it both ways can we?

No I'm no mystic but am fascinated by the likes of Blake or Ramanujan (Dec 2023) or Wordsworth (August) ppl who clearly have a hotline. And I find the OPs question relates quite closely to this hotline
